# how to save parsed data into two different lists

Tags: python, list, selenium, parsing

I have this code:

```
lokk = []
nums = 7
for _ in range(nums):
    inner = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/span[1]").get_attribute(
        "innerHTML")
    lokk.append(inner)
    time.sleep()
    print(lokk)
```

which provides me with this data:

`['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']`

what I want to do is to save that data into two different lists, the first list containing the first six values e.g. `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']`  and the second lists containing the the whole seven values e.g. `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']` how ever i want it be so that the next sample of data collected contains the last value of the second list as the first value of the list pair of lists like so `['7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13']`

i thought this was the code that would somewhat enable be to get the data in the different lists like i wanted but then soon realized that by the time it goes to fetch the second set of data for the second list of seven values, the data would have changed and that's not what I want

```
lok = []
num = 6
for _ in range(num):
    inner = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/span[1]").get_attribute(
        "innerHTML")
    lok.append(inner)
    time.sleep(10)
    print(lok)

lokk = []
nums = 7
for _ in range(nums):
    inner = driver.find_element_by_xpath(

"/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/span[1]").get_attribute(
        "innerHTML")
    lokk.append(inner)
    time.sleep()
    print(lokk)
```

Another flaw i saw in this is that when it was time to run the process again later, the seventh data would not be the first data for the new set of lists.
Meaning that instead of:

```
listA = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
listB = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
ListC = ['7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
listD = ['7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13']
```

it would be:

```
listA = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
listB = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
ListC = ['8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13']
listD = ['8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14']`
```

I really hope I was clear enough in what I am looking for assistance in, if not please let me know.
Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in many ways, try this:

For `ListC`:

```
    lok_c = []
    num_c = 13
    for _ in range(num_c):
        inner = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/span[1]").
get_attribute("innerHTML")
        if num_c > 7:
            lok_c.append(inner)
        time.sleep()
        print(lok_c)
```

For `ListD`:

```
    lok_d = []
    num_d = 14
    for _ in range(num_d):
        inner = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/span[1]").
get_attribute("innerHTML")
        if num_d > 7:
            lok_c.append(inner)
        time.sleep()
        print(lok_d)
```

Correct the indentation and variable name, if I missed anything.